# Help with choosing statistical test

Tags: correlation, kruskal-wallis-test, spearman-rho

I have a dataset consisting "Name of Power plant", "Year", "Status of compontent $1$", $\ldots$ "Status of compontent $n$", "Availability of power plant per year [%]", "Number of times the plant had interruptions" and "Number of hours with interuptions".

The status of each component is dichotomous, where 0 indicate status "bad" and 1 indicate "good". To consider the overall status of a Power plant the mean status of the $n$ Components is used. This gives $n+1$ levels of the overall status, $0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \ldots, 1$.

I am interested to test if it is possible to see a correlation between the status of the plant and each of the three measures "availability", "Number of interruptions" and "Hours with interruptions".

The test that I have done now is Kruskal-Wallis test to see if the distribution measure in each level of status is the same. And if they are the same we know that the mean and the variance is the same and then we can conclude that is it not possible to se differences of the measure in each level of status. In the case where the test shows that the distributions are not the same I have done a Spearman rho test to see find the correlation and if it is positive or negative.

Now my question is which test to use and if my way of testing with Kruskal-Wallis and Spearman rho is valid?